# Playlist maker with database (MusicBrainz) without needing files or streaming service?

Tags: music

I want to be able to make playlists of music that I don't necessarily have access to. This could include whether I upload them to a streaming service like Spotify or eventually buy the digital or hard copies. Or just for making playlists of my own music without having to reference specific files.

So I want an app that allows me to search a database, like MusicBrainz, for titles and add that metadata into a playlist which I can then download in some format.

I use Android for phone and linux for desktop but recs for other platforms welcome.

Something like Spotify comes close since you don't have to own them but I don't think you can 1) download the playlists (at least I haven't figured out how) and 2) is limited to just what is available on Spotify. I would rather it draw from something more open like MusicBrainz.